# order by asc and desc

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I need select some rows from table but that rows have to be ordered by `ROWNUMBER asc` and if `ROWNUMBER` is null i must order by `created desc`;

This is my sql query without order by condition;

```
SELECT FIN_CGU.*, RES.ROWNUMBER 
  FROM COMM$GROUP_USER FIN_CGU
  FULL JOIN (SELECT AGGR_RES.R_GR AS TOT_GR,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AGGR_RES.M_DATE DESC) AS ROWNUMBER
               FROM (SELECT MSG.GROUP_ID AS R_GR, MAX(MSG.CREATED) AS M_DATE
                       FROM COMM$MESSAGE MSG
                       JOIN COMM$GROUP_USER GR_USR
                         ON GR_USR.GROUP_ID = MSG.GROUP_ID
                       JOIN COMM$GROUP GR
                         ON GR.ID = MSG.GROUP_ID
                      WHERE GR.STATE <> 'DELETED'
                        AND GR_USR.STATE <> 'DELETED'
                        AND MSG.STATE <> 'DELETED'
                        AND GR_USR.USER_ID = 9172771513163989084
                      GROUP BY MSG.GROUP_ID) AGGR_RES
              ORDER BY AGGR_RES.M_DATE DESC) RES
    ON FIN_CGU.GROUP_ID = RES.TOT_GR
  JOIN COMM$GROUP CG
    ON FIN_CGU.GROUP_ID = CG.ID
 WHERE (ROWNUMBER IS NULL OR ROWNUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 3)
   AND FIN_CGU.USER_ID = 9172771513163989084
   AND RES.ROWNUM <= 3
 ORDER BY
```

Oracle 10g;

Comment: Is ORDER BY ROWNUMBER, CREATED DESC works for you? If not, what is a difference with desired result set? Can you add small example of desired ordering to question?

Answer (score 1):

1. it is unclear to what **created desc** you referred due to the fact that you've specified **FIN_CGU.***, and NOT the full column list.
2. if you were referring to the 
   *SELECT MSG.GROUP_ID AS R_GR, MAX(MSG.**CREATED**) AS M_DATE* and *created* in that list then you need to bring that column up from your dynamic view that are referenced as RES (and inside reference as AGGR_RES) to the top list of columns.
3. once you have that column in the list of columns it appears that your inner query should provide ordering; so you can do either by **case** or **nvl** as :

   order by case when ROWNUMBER is not null then ROWNUMBER  else created end
4. you cann't flip-flop asc|desc on the same column list dynamically on static query. you can do that in dynamic SQL. you **can change ordering column** though (  shown )